# Unable to learn a second inflection in this simple Tensorflow nnet?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, trigonometry

As a toy example I'm trying to fit a single hidden layer neural network to a sine wave. However, I only seem to be able to get the first inflection of the sine wave, after which it levels off and becomes flat:
[image: nnet output]
I've tried varying the amount of data, learning rate, hidden layer size, etc. but I always get something akin to this. Seems to me that something is fundamentally wrong in my code... From playing with this brilliant app this should be possible with 5-6 hidden units, although I've noticed that with certain weight initialisations it doesn't converge here either: http://neuron.eng.wayne.edu/bpFunctionApprox/bpFunctionApprox.html

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

hidden_units = 6 # 6 is theoretically a minimum for this function
epochs = 50
minibatch = 1

def shuffle_in_unison(a, b):
    rng_state = np.random.get_state()
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    np.random.set_state(rng_state)
    np.random.shuffle(b)

x_data = np.arange(0, 4 *np.pi, 0.3)
y_data = np.sin(x_data + np.pi)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, hidden_units], stddev=0.01), name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_units]), name="b")
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_units, 1], stddev=0.01), name="W2")
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="b2")

h = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y = tf.matmul(h, W2) + b2

squared_error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y)) # tf.abs similar result
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(squared_error)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

iterations = len(x_data) / minibatch
total_iterations = iterations * epochs

for epoch in range(epochs):
    tmp_x = x_data.copy()
    tmp_y = y_data.copy()
    shuffle_in_unison(tmp_x, tmp_y)
    for i in range(iterations):
        start_i = i*minibatch
        end_i   = (start_i + minibatch) % len(x_data) 
        x_batch = np.transpose(np.array([tmp_x[start_i:end_i]]))
        y_batch = np.transpose(np.array([tmp_y[start_i:end_i]]))
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: x_batch, y_: y_batch})

y_test = [y.eval(feed_dict={x:np.transpose(np.array([[a]]))})[0][0] for a in x_data]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.plot(x_data, y_test)
plt.legend(['Train', 'test'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: There is probably a bug somewhere. Can you try replacing the sine function with a simpler function and see if it fits it perfectly?